# How to handle multiple checkboxes

Tags: javascript, react-native, checkbox, console

I am working on a project in which I need to **filter results** on the basis of **checked items**. I want to select one or more than one item from different categories and also want to **consol.log(...)** selected items by clicking on the **Apply button** to know which items have been selected. Here is the **screenshot** of screen

[image]

**Here is my code**

const {
allergens,
cuisine,
deliveries,
dietagges,
environments,
services
} = this.state.data;

```
      <View style={styles.sliderContainer}>
        {allergens !== null && allergens !== undefined ? (
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.sliderLabel}>Allergens:</Text>
            {allergens.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <View style={styles.checkBoxContainer} key={index}>
                  <Text style={{ fontSize: 16 }}>
                    {item && item[0]}{" "}
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, color: "red" }}>
                      ({item && item[1]})
                    </Text>
                  </Text>
                  <CheckBox
                        checked={false}
                        onPress={() => this.handleValueChange()}
                  />
                </View>
              );
            })}
          </View>
        ) : null}
      </View>
<View style={styles.sliderContainer}>
            {environments !== null && environments !== undefined ? (
              <View>
                <Text style={styles.sliderLabel}>Environments:</Text>
                {environments.map((item, index) => {
                  return (
                    <View style={styles.checkBoxContainer} key={index}>
                      <Text style={{ fontSize: 16 }}>
                        {item && item[0]}{" "}
                        <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, color: "red" }}>
                          ({item && item[1]})
                        </Text>
                      </Text>
                      <CheckBox
                        checked={false}
                        onPress={() => this.handleValueChange()}
                      />
                    </View>
                  );
                })}
              </View>
            ) : null}
          </View>
          <View style={styles.sliderContainer}>
            {cuisine !== null && cuisine !== undefined ? (
              <View>
                <Text style={styles.sliderLabel}>Cuisine:</Text>
                {cuisine.map((item, index) => {
                  return (
                    <View style={styles.checkBoxContainer} key={index}>
                      <Text style={{ fontSize: 16 }}>
                        {item && item[0]}{" "}
                        <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, color: "red" }}>
                          ({item && item[1]})
                        </Text>
                      </Text>
                      <CheckBox
                        checked={false}
                        onPress={() => this.handleValueChange()}
                      />
                    </View>
                  );
                })}
              </View>
            ) : null}
          </View>
```

And here is the **data** coming from **API**

```
"cuisine": [
                    [
                        "Middle Eastern",
                        4
                    ],
                    [
                        "Western",
                        4
                    ],
                    [
                        "Pasta Dishes",
                        2
                    ],
                    [
                        "Salad",
                        2
                    ],
                    [
                        "Mexican",
                        1
                    ],
                    [
                        "Soup",
                        1
                    ],
                    [
                        "snacks",
                        1
                    ]
                ],
                "allergens": [
                    [
                        "Halal",
                        14
                    ]
                ],
                "environments": [
                    [
                        "Mexican",
                        15
                    ]
                ],
```

How to select or unselect items without affecting others?
What is the solution of this problem. If this approach is not good then what will be the alternatives to accomplish this task. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Update: working example with React + JSX:

https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-snyder-kxh67

You can try this way:

```
<View style={styles.sliderContainer}>
        {allergens !== null && allergens !== undefined ? (
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.sliderLabel}>Allergens:</Text>
            {allergens.map((item, index) => {
              const key = `checkbox_${index}_value`;
              return (
                <View style={styles.checkBoxContainer} key={index}>
                  <Text style={{ fontSize: 16 }}>
                    {item && item[0]}{" "}
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, color: "red" }}>
                      ({item && item[1]})
                    </Text>
                  </Text>
                  <CheckBox
                        onChange={() => this.handleValueChange(index)}
                        value={ this.state[key] || false }
                  />
                </View>
              );
            })}
          </View>
        ) : null}
      </View>
```

```
handleValueChange = (index) => {
   const key = `checkbox_${index}_value`;
   const newValue = !!!this.state[key];
   this.setState({
     [key]: newValue,
   }, () => {
     console.log('value changed: ', index, newValue);
   });

}
```

getting all values:

```
getCheckboxes = () => {
  const values = this.state.data.allergens.map((v, index) => {
    const key = `checkbox_${index}_value`;
    const value = this.state[key] || false;
    return { index, value };
  });
  console.log('Checkboxes values: ', values);
}
```

Comment: values are changing when handleValueChange function call but when I call getCheckboxes it gives undefined. Why this is happening?

Comment: i fixed a typo, return this.state[key]; instead of return this.state.key inside map callback

Comment: It returns only one value but I want to console.log(...) all selected checkboxes. How to do this?

Comment: I have updated getCheckboxes, now it should return all values.

Comment: Its giving { index: 0 value: true } but I selected four values so there should be four objects. Am I right?

Comment: Are you calling getCheckboxes on "Apply" button press when 4 checkboxes are checked? Yes, values should contain an array of objects.

Comment: Yes, I am doing the same but its only shows this { index: 0 value: true } either I selected one or more than one checkboxes. And it also not toggling the checkboxes.

Comment: I wrote a working online examaple with React+JSX https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-snyder-kxh67

Answer (score -1):

declare state like this.state = { SelectedItem: []}

1. Pass current cuisine name in "this.handleValueChange(item[0])"
2. On this.handleValueChange(item) function,

Check whether current item exist in this.state.selectedItem ?
Then pop if else push it to array. And save state.

3. Console.log(this.state.selectedItem) on apply button press

Hope it will help.